# Automatic image scaling on resize with (Py)GTK

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a `GtkImage` widget in a resizable window and a reference `GdkPixBuf` storing the image I want to fill the `GtkImage` with.

I can scale the `GdkPixBuf` to fill the `GtkImage` widget using this method:

```
def update_image(self, widget=None, data=None):
    # Get the size of the source pixmap
    src_width, src_height = self.current_image.get_width(), self.current_image.get_height()

    # Get the size of the widget area
    widget = self.builder.get_object('image')
    allocation = widget.get_allocation()
    dst_width, dst_height = allocation.width, allocation.height

    # Scale preserving ratio
    scale = min(float(dst_width)/src_width, float(dst_height)/src_height)
    new_width = int(scale*src_width)
    new_height = int(scale*src_height)
    pixbuf = self.current_image.scale_simple(new_width, new_height, gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR)

    # Put the generated pixbuf in the GtkImage widget
    widget.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
```

When I call `update_image` manually it works as expected. Now I want the scaling to occur automatically when the GtkImage widget is resized. The best solution I came with was to bind the `update_image` method to the `configure-event` GTK event of the window. After each size change of the window, the image is indeed properly scaled. However I have two issues with this solution:

- I can only make the window bigger. Once the image has been upscaled, GTK won't let me resize the window smaller because the window can't be smaller than its widgets. I understand why it works like that but I don't know how to change this behaviour.
- Maybe this is no big deal but I would have preferred an event from the GtkImage widget instead of the top-level window.

I am sorry for the long explanation of such a trivial problem, I hope you'll be able to help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you could use [expose-event](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#signal-gtkwidget--expose-event) signal of the widget for image scaling. Also adding image into scrollable container should fix the problem with window resize. Please check if an example below would work for you.

```
import gtk

class ScaleImage:
    def __init__(self):
        self.temp_height = 0
        self.temp_width = 0

        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)

        image = gtk.Image()
        image.set_from_file('/home/my_test_image.jpg')
        self.pixbuf = image.get_pixbuf()
        image.connect('expose-event', self.on_image_resize, window)    

        box = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        box.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
        box.add(image)

        window.add(box)
        window.set_size_request(300, 300)
        window.show_all()        

    def on_image_resize(self, widget, event, window):
        allocation = widget.get_allocation()
        if self.temp_height != allocation.height or self.temp_width != allocation.width:
            self.temp_height = allocation.height
            self.temp_width = allocation.width
            pixbuf = self.pixbuf.scale_simple(allocation.width, allocation.height, gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR)
            widget.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)

    def close_application(self, widget, event, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScaleImage()
    gtk.main()
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Thanks a lot, the ScrolledWindow trick worked. I get a `GtkWarning: gtk_scrolled_window_add(): cannot add non scrollable widget use gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport() instead` but if I add a viewport then scrollbars appear when I am reducing the size of the window so I'll leave it like that for now. The `expose-event` is called on each gtk iteration so it maxed the cpu usage.

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated with GTK+ 3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49754093/6094756

Answer (score 2):

All widgets have [`size-allocate`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-size-allocate) (cf. [PyGObject Gtk3](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.signals.size_allocate)) signal.

> The "size-allocate" signal is emitted when widget is given a new space allocation.

Perhaps you can use that.

Comment: I used the `"configure-event"` signal in C before, which didn't work properly for this purpose. Now with `"size-allocate"` I have no more problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a `GtkScrolledWindow`, you can replace your `GtkImage` with a `GtkDrawingArea` instead, and then draw your image using Cairo. This will allow the images to shrink, because `GtkDrawingArea` does not set a size request.

I don't know about Python, but here is an example in C using GTK3:

```
gboolean drawing_area_draw (GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, GdkPixbuf *current_image)
{

    .....   //Calculate size

    pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple (current_image,
                                    new_width,
                                    new_height,
                                    GDK_INTERP_BILINEAR);

    gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf (cr, 
                                pixbuf,
                                allocation.width/2 - new_width/2, 
                                allocation.height/2 - new_height/2);
    cairo_paint (cr);

    return FALSE;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    .....

    drawing_area = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (drawing_area), "draw",
            G_CALLBACK (drawing_area_draw), current_image);

    .....
}
```

If the drawing area's background appears opaque, set `gtk_widget_set_has_window ()` to `FALSE`, though it's probably better to derive your own widget from `GtkDrawingArea` and set this property in its `init` function.

If you're using GTK2, the code is similar, except that you have to call `gdk_cairo_create ()` on `widget->window` and call `cairo_destroy ()` when you're finished.

Also, with GTK2, if the `GtkDrawingArea` doesn't have its own `GdkWindow`, the coordinates for drawing are relative to the parent `GdkWindow` rather than the widget.