# how to do automatic image resizing in Python3 with PyGI?

Tags: image, python-3.x, resize, gtk, introspection

Although I have found partial and indirect answers to this question (see, e.g., [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939734/automatic-image-scaling-on-resize-with-pygtk)), I am posting this here because putting together the bits and pieces of the puzzle took me a bit of time, and I thought someone else might find my efforts of use.

So, how to achieve a seamless resizing of images on buttons in GTK+ when the parent window is resized?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution offered for PyGTK in the link posted in the question does not work in Python-GI with GTK3, although the trick of using a ScrolledWindow in place of the usual Box was very useful.

Here is my minimal working solution to getting an image on a button to resize with the container.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf

class ButtonWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Button Demo")
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.connect("check_resize", self.on_check_resize)

        self.box = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.box.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.ALWAYS,
                       Gtk.PolicyType.ALWAYS)
        self.add(self.box)

        self.click = Gtk.Button()
        self.box.add_with_viewport(self.click)

        self.pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf().new_from_file('gtk-logo-rgb.jpg')
        self.image = Gtk.Image().new_from_pixbuf(self.pixbuf)
        self.click.add(self.image)

    def resizeImage(self, x, y):
        print('Resizing Image to ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')....')
        pixbuf = self.pixbuf.scale_simple(x, y,
                                          GdkPixbuf.InterpType.BILINEAR)
        self.image.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)

    def on_check_resize(self, window):
        print("Checking resize....")

        boxAllocation = self.box.get_allocation()
        self.click.set_allocation(boxAllocation)
        self.resizeImage(boxAllocation.width-10,
                         boxAllocation.height-10)

win = ButtonWindow()
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

(The -10 on the width and height are to accommodate the inner borders and padding in the button. I tried fiddling with this to get a bigger image on the button, but the result did not look so nice.)

The jpeg file used in this example can be downloaded from [here](http://ftp5.jp.netbsd.org/pub/X/gimp/users/timj/gtk-logo-rgb.jpg).

I welcome further suggestions on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`self.image = Gtk.Image().new_from_pixbuf(self.pixbuf)` 
Should probably be: 
`self.image = Gtk.Image().set_from_pixbuf(self.pixbuf)`

You're creating a new image twice.

Comment: I tried changing to this method in my test program and just got a traceback (Python 3.2, Debian Wheezy). Possibly this method is newer to the API (but the documentation seems to contradict that). But reading the documentation I think you are wrong about creating the image twice ( see [`set_from_pixbuf`](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkimage.html#method-gtkimage--set-from-pixbuf) and [`new_from_pixbuf`](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkimage.html#function-gtk--image-new-from-pixbuf)). They both create a new image from the pixbuf. There is one pixbuf, one image.